# How to properly setup facebook comment moderation tool?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, facebook

I have added fb comments plugin on my django site, and would like to also use fb's moderation tool to moderate the comments on the pages involved. Previous dev made a mistake of not properly passing appId to the script, and I have rectified that. The problem is, some of the pages (without any comments present) do register new comments on the moderation tool, while others do not even though its the same template being used.

Im including the related html and js code that I am using on the template

```js
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId={{ SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY }}&xbfml=true&autoLogAppEvents=1"
  {% endif %}
  
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{ SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY }}"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ article_url }}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ article.title }}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ article.content|striptags|truncatechars:200 }}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ article_full_image_url }}" />


<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://{{ SITE.domain }}{{ LURL }}{{ request.path_info }}" data-num-posts="2" data-width="100%"></div>
```

So the facebook sharing debugger tool picks up every meta tag properly, just comments are not being picked up on certain pages, while some do show up on the comment moderation tool.

Comment: Why is what you pointed the comments plugin to, different from what you output as `og:url`?

Comment: ahh, that is for testing purposes, but essentially urls are the same for both

Comment: Did you re-scrape the URLs in question, so that Facebook’s cache of the OG meta data is up to date?

Comment: yeah a lot of times